# Package 'libssl1.0.0' has no installation candidate

Tags: debian

Where can I find this library specifically for installing and using msserver express on debian? I get this error.

```
sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends     libssl1.0.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libssl1.0.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libssl1.0.0' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use an old version of SQL server; from a quick look I concluded only the Ubuntu 16.04 packages are linked against OpenSSL 1.0 (which is unsupported); more recent builds appear to require OpenSSL 1.1 (which does still have security support). Try finding more recent builds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that `libssl1.0.0` is **obsolete** and no longer updated; any binary linking to it probably suffers from various security issues (perhaps not exploitable, but you’d need to determine that in your scenarios). You should really look for a newer version of whatever it is you’re trying to use.

However, you *can* find [`libssl1.0.0` on Debian snapshots](http://snapshot.debian.org/binary/libssl1.0.0/); download the appropriate package and install it. For example on `amd64`:

```
wget http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20170705T160707Z/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2l-1%7Ebpo8%2B1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.0*.deb
```

You may need to install `multiarch-support` first:

```
wget http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20190501T215844Z/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.28-10_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i multiarch-support*.deb
```

(Having this library installed only affects binaries which link to it; it won’t create security issues for other binaries linking to other versions of the library.)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a libssl1.1 issue when trying to install mongo-db in Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS (or Ubuntu 22.04 LTS).

[As **@stephen-kitt** mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/688289/318461) **libssl1.x** is an **obsolete** package. So you need to manually install the required package.

1. Go to [this page](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl)
2. Find the exact version of libssl for example **libssl1.1.1**
3. `wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.20_amd64.deb` (use your version url respectively)
4. Then install with `sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.20_amd64.deb`

Hope this helps others who are trying to do the same.

The issue [is referenced on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/24759), all credit goes to **@feisalramar**.

Comment: This is *related* to the question, but the question is specifically about `libssl1.0.0` on Debian. If you want to ensure the fix for `libssl1.1` on Ubuntu is documented on Unix.SE, please ask a new question (you’ll be able to answer it yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Edit following file

```
# sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following line

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
```

```
# sudo apt update && apt-cache policy libssl1.0-dev
# sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```

Reference Link: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4918#issuecomment-1031242032

Comment: Note that if you’re interested in `rvm` specifically, [the correct fix is to use the Ubuntu `rvm` PPA](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4918#issuecomment-660219259).